# Connect tfs express 2015 to Visual Studio 2005

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2005, source-control

I have installed on my Windows 10 machine VS2005 and VS2015.
I have created a server with TFS 2015 express.
I am able to configure TFS on VS2015 with no issues.
I would like to have TFS also on VS2005.

I couldn't find the correct installation to make it works.

I tried the following installations and got the below error messages:

1. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22d38324-051c-4f04-9379-ff78e7116c8d

[image]

2. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3263

[image]

What do I need to install in order to have TFS 2015 express working on VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [this](https://tfs.discountasp.net/kb/a840/configure-visual-studio-2005-to-connect-to-your-team-foundation-server.aspx) and it fixes my issues.